# Mono 4 (3.1.2 worked fine), Could not load type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderContext

Tags: c#, mono, nancy

My application works fine on Mono 3.1.2, but as soon as I upgrade to mono 4.0 my application fails to start with:

Could not load type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be occurring?  I'm using NancyHost which is causing the problem.

Here is the full stack trace:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderContext' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.   at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpGetIndexBinder.FallbackGetIndex
>   (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] indexes,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Dynamic.GetIndexBinder.FallbackGetIndex
>   (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] indexes) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindGetIndex
>   (System.Dynamic.GetIndexBinder binder,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] indexes) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Dynamic.DynamicObject+MetaDynamic.BindGetIndex
>   (System.Dynamic.GetIndexBinder binder,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] indexes) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Dynamic.GetIndexBinder.Bind
>   (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind
>   (System.Object[] args,
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.LabelTarget returnLabel) [0x00000] in
>   <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[Func`4]
>   (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1 site, System.Object[]
>   args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[Object,String,Object]
>   (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, System.Object arg0,
>   System.String arg1) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Nancy.Conventions.BuiltInCultureConventions.FormCulture
>   (Nancy.NancyContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Nancy.Culture.DefaultCultureService.DetermineCurrentCulture
>   (Nancy.NancyContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Nancy.DefaultNancyContextFactory.Create (Nancy.Request request)
>   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache..ctor
>   (INancyModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, INancyContextFactory
>   contextFactory, IRouteSegmentExtractor routeSegmentExtractor,
>   IRouteDescriptionProvider routeDescriptionProvider, ICultureService
>   cultureService, IEnumerable`1 routeMetadataProviders) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Nancy.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsHook.Enable
>   (Nancy.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration diagnosticsConfiguration,
>   IPipelines pipelines, IEnumerable`1 providers, IRootPathProvider
>   rootPathProvider, IRequestTracing requestTracing,
>   Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyInternalConfiguration configuration,
>   IModelBinderLocator modelBinderLocator, IEnumerable`1
>   responseProcessors, IEnumerable`1 routeSegmentConstraints,
>   ICultureService cultureService, IRequestTraceFactory
>   requestTraceFactory, IEnumerable`1 routeMetadataProviders,
>   ITextResource textResource) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Nancy.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnostics.Initialize (IPipelines pipelines)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1[Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer].Initialise
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor (INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper,
>   Nancy.Hosting.Self.HostConfiguration configuration, System.Uri[]
>   baseUris) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor (System.Uri baseUri,
>   INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, Nancy.Hosting.Self.HostConfiguration
>   configuration) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory, the **RuntimeBinderContext** type does not exists in Microsoft.CSharp assembly in Mono 4.0.0

If you look closely at the Image below, you'll see those are the only types defined for the assembly, among those there's no RuntimeBinderContext. Hence the error.

[image: Disassembly of Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0.0]

I know this is not a solution to your problem, I'm dealing with the same situation here. I will post if If I find a solution. But I wanted to point you in the direction to why you're getting this error.

Comment: Appreciate the detail.  What is strange is the mono project HAS this class, and the methods defined.  I'm not sure why it isn't in 4.0.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Microsoft.CSharp/Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder/RuntimeBinderContext.cs

Comment: Were you ever able to determine anything @javier? I opened a bug w/mono but haven't heard anything.

Comment: @Geesu I ended up removing Mono.CSharp.dll from my bin folder. It turned out to be imported without need and was breaking the execution. I didnt go deeper on this, sorry.